# Updating local repo everytime original repo is changed

Tags: node.js, github, digital-ocean

I have a project running on a remote server. I cloned it into the server to run. Problem is everytime I make a change to the code via git, I have to go into the remote server delete the folder and clone it once again. How can it automatically detect a change in the repo and update it?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for what's called continuous deployment|delivery.

Since you're using GitHub, you may want to look at [GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions). This is one of many mechanisms that are available.

You can configure Actions to trigger various actions (including building, testing and deployment of your code [to the Digital Ocean droplet]) every time you make a commit.